# Resolve new data in already resolved promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a single page app in angular. There is a global available state available through a context service.

This context service has a get and set method. The get method is a promise since the context is not yet set up once the page is loaded but is gotten through an API.

Once the context is set-up the promise is resolved and I can access my context through the get method.

However how can I deal with the set method. It is possible to change the context with the set method. But since the promise is already resolved the get method will return the old context.

Is it possible to 'substitute' the data the promise returns on a then call after it has been resolved?

Thanks!

Comment: No, this is not possible. The code has already been run, in that case you have to store the then callback and call it again.

Comment: you can use rxjs streams subscribe  then, whenever new data is available , your callback is called then,

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words. Show an [mcve] of exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Consider just calling `contextService.get` a second time. With a good caching policy, you can avoid actually making repetitive HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The get method is a promise...

That doesn't make much sense. I'm assuming it *returns* a promise.

> However how can I deal with the set method. It is possible to change the context with the set method. But since the promise is allready resolved the get method will return the old context.

Code shouldn't keep and reuse the old promise like that. E.g., you're suggesting:

```
var p = object.getThePromise();
p.then(function(value) {
    // ...use the value...
});
// later - this is the bit that's wrong
p.then(function(value) {
    // ...use the value...
});
```

It shouldn't do that. It should go back to `getThePromise` if it wants the value again later (if it wants a new value).

> Is it possible to 'substitute' the data the promise returns on a then call after it has been resolved?

No. An important part of the promise contract is that a promise is only ever settled once, and the settled value does not change.

It's hard to say without seeing your API, but if the API gives the impression you can call the "get" and then reuse the resulting promise, it would be best to change the API to make it no longer give that impression. But again, without API specifics, it's hard to say whether that's the case or suggest a change.